# PHP does not execute in chrome addon

Tags: php, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, add-on

I am developing a chrome addon. I have used PHP in it to email the user. The PHP part does not execute when I am running the addon. Is this because there is no server? How do I test it with XAMP or any tool that creates a server? Please guide.

Edit:

Until I get a better answer, I am giving a try to this addon for it:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-logger/noaneddfkdjfnfdakjjmocngnfkfehhd

Here s a snapshot of how the PHP shows up(obviously its the server issue. )
[image]

Comment: PHP is server-side ***only***. I don't know what language Chrome addons are supposed to be written in, but I am positive that it is not PHP.

Comment: @Sammitch: I agree with you. They use html, css and Javascript. I have made my extension using html,css which calls PHP as I need to email the user via the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this, you need to use html,css,javascript: [chromeaddons](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)

Comment: That is right. I have the basic extension in html and css but I need to email the user as he presses send button. There I call PHP.

Comment: I advise you to use the html local storage function, it isn't good to use php for browser extensions.. There is the w3c link: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Thanks. After reading some blogs, I figured out that Google may look at such things as a malware. I will follow your advice.